# Please help me solve the inequality$ |x^2 - 7 x + 12| < | x - 4 |$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

[Here's my attempt.](https://pasteboard.co/ImqXwDh.jpg) Is it correct? Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to stack-exchange. It is preferred to use mathjax in order to write your attempt into the body text instead of linking to an image.

Comment: Please type your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) where possible, instead of linking images.  Images can't be browsed and aren't accessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: Sorry I am new here. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: you can spot that $x^2 - 7x + 12 = (x - 4)(x - 3)$ and open up the absolute values by considering 3 intervals for $x$: $(-\infty, 3)$, $(3, 4)$ and $(4, +\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Another way:** note that $|x^2-7x+12|=|x-4||x-3|$. Then
$$|x-4||x-3|<|x-4|$$
$$\frac{|x-4||x-3|}{|x-4|}<1$$
Clearly, $ x = 4 $ does not satisfy the inequality, so we can avoid it (cancel the respective terms) and this gives us
$$|x-3|<1$$
that is $2<x<4$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @pointguard0 as a starting point:

$ |x^2 - 7 x + 12| < | x - 4 |$ is the same as $ |(x-3)(x-4)| < | x - 4 |$

If $x>4$, you can get rid of all the absolute values and write $ (x-3)(x-4) <  (x - 4) $, thus $(x-3) < 0$ (which never happens)

If $x \in (3, 4)$, we get $ -(x-3)(x-4) <  -(x - 4) $, or, simplified, $(x-3) < 1$, which always happens. The sign is inverted because (x-4) is negative

Finally, if x<3, what we get is $(x-3)(x-4) <  -(x - 4) $, which simplifies to $(x-3) > -1$, in short, $x>2$

The statement is obviously false for x=4 and true for x=3. In conclusion, it is true if $x \in (2,4)

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Write your inequality in the form
$$|x-3||x-4|<|x-4|$$